# Proof writing involving union and intersection: $A\cap B=A\cup B=B\cap C=B\cup C \Rightarrow A=B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Prove:** $$A\cap B=A\cup B=B\cap C=B\cup C \Rightarrow A=B=C$$

**Part 1:**
Suppose $x_1\in A$, then $x_1\in A\cup B$. So then $x_1\in A\cap B$. Thus $x_1\in B$ and thus $A\subseteq B$.

Suppose $x_2\in B$, then $x_2\in A\cup B$. So then $x\in A\cap B$. Thus $x_2\in A$ and thus $B\subseteq A$.

Therefore, $A = B$.

**Part 2:** 
Suppose $x∈B$, then $x∈B∪C$. So then $x∈B∩C$. Thus $x∈C$ and thus $B⊆C$

Suppose $x∈C$, then $x∈B∪C$. So then $x∈B∩C$. Thus $x∈B$ and thus $C⊆B$

Therefore, $B = C$.

**Thus**, if **part 1 & 2** are equal, then $A=B=C$

Is this correct? Another way to prove this? Tips for a better proof writing?

Comment: I would get rid of "Thus, if part 1 & 2 are equal". What does it mean for parts to be equal?

Comment: Looks good to me :)

Comment: Additionally, relabeling $A$ from part 1 as $C$ proves part 2, without having to go through all the steps again.

Comment: @AdinaGoldberg elaborate please?

Comment: I mean, you've done the same proof twice, once to show $A=B$, assuming that $A\cap B = A\cup B$ and once to show $B=C$, assuming that $B\cap C = B\cup C$. They are exactly the same except for what you call the sets.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that stylistically, it's neater to first show that for any sets $X, Y$ with $X\cap Y = X\cup Y$, we must have that $X=Y$ (which is what you did in Part 1). Then, directly from your assumptions, you have $A=B$ and $B=C$ and you're done.

Comment: Either way, your proof looks correct to me!

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @AdinaGoldberg how could you break this statement into two? is this valid A∩B=A∪B → A=B ↔ B∩C=B∪C→B=C or A∩B=A∪B = A=B ↔ B∩C=B∪C = B=C or simply A∩B=A∪B  ↔ B∩C=B∪C ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29546/discussion-between-adina-goldberg-and-steve).

Answer (score 2):

Your work is correct. This is an alternative proof without using elements:

We have
$$A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B\setminus A)$$
and this union is disjoint so since $A\cup B=A\cap B$ then $A\setminus B=B\setminus A=\emptyset$ so $A=B$. Do the same method for the set $C$.